# NuxtJS store returning local storage values as undefined

Tags: asynchronous, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a nuxt application. One of the components in it's mounted lifecycle hook is requesting a value from the state store, this value is retrieved from local storage. The values exist in local storage however the store returns it as undefined. If I render the values in the ui with {{value}}
they show. So it appears that in the moment that the code runs, the value is undefined.

index.js (store):

```js
export const state = () => ({
  token: process.browser ? localStorage.getItem("token") : undefined,
  user_id: process.browser ? localStorage.getItem("user_id") : undefined,
...
```

Component.vue

mounted hook:
I'm using UserSerivce.getFromStorage to get the value directly from localStorage as otherwise this  code block won't run. It's a temporary thing to illustrate the problem.

```js
async mounted() {
  // check again with new code. 
  if (UserService.getFromStorage("token")) {
    console.log("user service found a token but what about store?")
    console.log(this.$store.state.token, this.$store.state.user_id);

    const values = await ["token", "user_id"].map(key => {return UserService.getFromStorage(key)});
    console.log({values});
    SocketService.trackSession(this, socket, "connect")
  }
}
```

BeforeMount hook:

isLoggedIn just checks that the "token" property is set in the store state.
`return !!this.$store.state.token`

```js
beforeMount () {
  if (this.isLoggedIn) {
    // This runs sometimes??? 80% of the time.
    console.log("IS THIS CLAUSE RUNNING?");
  }
}
```

video explanation: https://www.loom.com/share/541ed2f77d3f46eeb5c2436f761442f4

Comment: Well asked question! There is a lot of things happening here. It is probably a lifecyle issue or something being async and not blocked until resolution? Will be hard to debug it like this. Faster way is probably to create a brand new project and double-check all the possible issues. Then, trying to comment out and `console.log`/use the debugger. Since it's 80% of the time, this is probably it.

Comment: Also, you need to know that `mount` is not blocking in the case of an `async/await`.

Comment: Also, are you using `ssr` or not? Because a `target: 'static'` + `ssr: true` is more tricky than a regular `ssr: false`.

Comment: in regards to ssr - Whatever the default for nuxt is.
I don't have the field explicitly set in the nuxt.config.js file 
(embarrassing oops. I'm relatively new to vue)

Comment: Here are the defaults: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ssr and the other one: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-target

Comment: I feared that might be the issue. Something blocking which is causing the value to return as undefined. It's a big app, so that's gonna take some time :(

Comment: Also, prefer using `fetch()` or `asyncData()` maybe since those are a bit more suited into a Nuxt context.

Comment: okay so putting ssr: to false fixes the problem, but causes some issues with another part of the app - but that you!.

debugging is like playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: The issue is that those kind of things need to be decided at the beginning and have quite an impact in the long run because of the way Nuxt behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's app is quite big from what it looks, so finding the exact reason is kinda difficult.
Meanwhile, setting `ssr: false` fixed the errors.

It raised more, but they should probably be asked into another question nonetheless.